# how to remove a stop word from default _english_ stop-words list in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, stop-words

I am filtering the text using default English stop-words. I found 'and' is a stop-word in English, but I need to search for the results containing 'and'. I just want to remove `and` word from this default English stop-words filter and use other stopwords as usually. My elasticsearch schema looks similar to below.

```
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace" ,
          "filter": ["stop_english"]
        } 
       }....,
       "filter":{
         "stop_english": {
            "type": "stop",
            "stopwords": "_english_"
        }
}
```

I expect to see the docs containing `AND` word with _search api.

Answer (score 0):

You can [set the stop words](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html) for a given index manually like this:

```
PUT /my_index
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "my_stop": {
                    "type":       "stop",
                    "stopwords": ["and", "is", "the"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also found the list of English stop words used by elasticsearch [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/i-want-to-know-the-word-list-of-the---english---stop-token-filter/96930). If you manage to manually set the same list of stop words minus "and" in an index and reindex you data in the newly configured index with the good stop words , you should be good to go!

regarding reindexation of your data, you should check out the [reindex api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html). I believe it is required since the tokenization of your data happens at ingestion time so you need to redo the ingestion by reindexing it. It is requires most of the time when changing index settings or some mapping changes (not 100% sure, but i think it makes sense).

Comment: FYI, ElasticSearch documentation at this moment of time points here for stop words used by different language analyzers [here][1].


  [1]: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html#english-stop-words